# Llegar hasta un botón mediante jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, daterangepicker

Estoy intentando alcanzar un botón, el mismo tiene la clase `cancelButton2`, y se crea dinámicamente mediante el plugin `daterangepicker`. El tema es que utilizo dos rangos en dos páginas distintas del sitio, y quiero diferenciar el rango de una al rango de la otra. La diferencia está en una clase que tiene un `div` padre de los elementos `cancelButton2`.

```
<div class="daterangepicker ltr show-ranges opensright" style="display: block; top: 187px; left: 1642.83px; right: auto;">
    <div class="cancelar">
        <button class="cancelBtn2 btn btn-xs btn-block btn-info align-content-center" type="button">Reiniciar Rango</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eliminé de ese código un montón de `divs` que estaban antes que el de la clase `cancelBtn2`, pero entiendo que no hace parte del problema.

En el caso de la otra página, el `html` es prácticamente igual, a excepción de que el elemento de la clase `daterangepicker`, en lugar de tener la clase `opensright` tiene la clase `opensleft`.

```
<div class="daterangepicker ltr show-ranges opensleft" style="display: block; top: 187px; left: 1642.83px; right: auto;">
    <div class="cancelar">
        <button class="cancelBtn2 btn btn-xs btn-block btn-info align-content-center" type="button">Reiniciar Rango</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ahí es donde quiero diferenciarlos, y trato de hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero no funciona, el botón de la clase `cancelBtn2` no ejecuta ninguna acción.

```
$(".daterangepicker .opensright .cancelar .cancelBtn2").on("click", function() {
    //acciones del botón
})
```

Comment: Pero está en dos paginas distintas? con eso no te causaría conflicto.

Comment: El boton se genera desde un plugin, y como veras no tiene atributo id, si lo tuviera, de todas maneras se me estaría repitiendo y tendria el mismo problema que tengo ahora, pero ademas tendría el problema que vos decis. En este caso tienen nombres de clases, entiendo que de esa manera no hay conflicto. La cosa es que yo necesito que el boton reaccione de una manera u otra depende la pagina en la que estoy, por eso solo necesito alcanzarlo, ja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el selector.

```
.daterangepicker .opensright .cancelar .cancelBtn2
```

Con ese selector lo que estás diciendo es que encuentre un elemento con la clase `.cancelBtn2`, que tenga un ancestro de la clase `.cancelar`, que a su vez tenga un ancestro de la clase `.opensright` y que este tenga un ancestro de la clase `.daterangepicker`.

¿Qué es lo que ocurre? Que ese elemento no existe en tu documento. Por el contrario si que existe un elemento que es de la clase `.cancelBtn2`, que tiene un ancestro de la clase `.cancelar` y que tiene un ancestro con las clases `.opensright` y `.daterangepicker`.

Para seleccionar un elemento por dos de sus clases estas deben ir consecutivas, ya que el espacio entre elementos indica un cambio de nivel de parentesco.

```
.daterangepicker.opensright .cancelar .cancelBtn2
```

**Ejemplo:**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".daterangepicker .opensright .cancelar .cancelBtn2").on("click", function() {
      console.log('No funciono porque no existe ningún elemento que coincida con el selector');
  })
  
  $(".daterangepicker.opensright .cancelar .cancelBtn2").on("click", function() {
      console.log('¡Te encontré!');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterangepicker ltr show-ranges opensright" style="display: block; top: 187px; left: 1642.83px; right: auto;">
    <div class="cancelar">
        <button class="cancelBtn2 btn btn-xs btn-block btn-info align-content-center" type="button">Reiniciar Rango</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, no es ese el problema, de hecho funciona bien si solo utilizo ``$(".cancelBtn2").on("click", function() {}``, y lo tengo en una sola pagina. El tema es cuando agrego la funcion para la segunda pagina. La accion que debe realizar el boton es vaciar una varable en el localStorage y redireccionar a la pagina en la que me encuentro. Y para hacer esas dos acciones necesito diferenciar un botón del otro.

Comment: Creo que te comprendo. Dame un par de minutos.

Comment: Edité la pregunta con lo que pienso que puede ser la solución.